# sort merge join strategy still have sort step though pre sort data in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, join, pyspark, mergesort

```
data = [(1, "Alice", "A"),
        (3, "Charlie", "A"),
        (2, "Bob", "B"),
        (4, "David", "B")]
schema = ["id", "name", "partition_key"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

df.repartition(2, f.col("id")).write.mode("overwrite")\
 .format("parquet") \
 .bucketBy(2, "id") \
 .sortBy("id") \
 .option("compression", "snappy") \
 .saveAsTable("bucketed_table_H")


spark.sql("""
select *
from bucketed_table_H a join bucketed_table_H b
on a.id = b.id
""").explain(True)
```

i see plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- SortMergeJoin [id#24L], [id#27L], Inner
   :- Sort [id#24L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Filter isnotnull(id#24L)
   :     +- FileScan parquet default.bucketed_table_h[id#24L,name#25,partition_key#26] Batched: true, Bucketed: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(id#24L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint,name:string,partition_key:string>, SelectedBucketsCount: 2 out of 2
   +- Sort [id#27L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Filter isnotnull(id#27L)
         +- FileScan parquet default.bucketed_table_h[id#27L,name#28,partition_key#29] Batched: true, Bucketed: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(id#27L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file.., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint,name:string,partition_key:string>, SelectedBucketsCount: 2 out of 2
```

me why this still have sort step?

i try following post: [Why does Spark re-sort the data when the join of the two tables are bucketed and sorted the same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73346771/why-does-spark-re-sort-the-data-when-the-join-of-the-two-tables-are-bucketed-and/77467470#77467470)

but i see plan still have sort step

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Exchange` in the Plan. That's the point.

Sorting is for the MergeSort. Standard approach. See https://towardsdatascience.com/strategies-of-spark-join-c0e7b4572bcf

Aka it's working fine.

Quote from SO answer: ‘Even with the same partitioner, it is unclear whether rows are sorted within each partition.’